# Does Elixir library files automatically reload?

Tags: elixir

Does Elixir library files automatically reload if I change/modify the libraries that it's calling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Some libraries like [exreloader](https://github.com/yrashk/exreloader) reload the files after they are compiled. Projects like [Dynamo](https://github.com/dynamo/dynamo) have their own mechanisms.